# How to Display Option Labels Instead of Values in Sitecore Forms Autoresponder Emails?

Tags: sitecore-forms

I'm working with Sitecore Forms in SC10 and have encountered a challenge with the autoresponder email functionality. In my form, there's a list field named **"How will you use your new home?"** with options such as **"Owner Occupier"** and **"Investor"**, which internally are stored with values **"tfa_1"** and **"tfa_2"**, respectively.

When setting up the autoresponder email to include the user's selection, I use the placeholder `[How will you use your new home]` in the email template. However, the autoresponder email displays the value of the selected option (e.g., **"tfa_1"** or **"tfa_2"**) instead of the display text (**"Owner Occupier"** or **"Investor"**).

Is there a way in Sitecore Forms to configure the autoresponder email so that it shows the display name or label of the selected option (**"Owner Occupier"** or **"Investor"**) instead of its value (**"tfa_1"** or **"tfa_2"**)? I'm looking for a solution that can either be configured directly in Sitecore or through custom development if necessary.

Thanks in advance